# PDOException on Duplicate filename in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Using the following code:

```
foreach ($form_state['values']['uploads'] as $key => $value) {
if (strlen($value)) {
  $file = file_save_upload($key, array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(), // Validates file is really an image. 
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'), // Validate extensions.
  ));
  // If the file passed validation:
  if ($file) {
    // Move the file, into the Drupal file system
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
     // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
     $form_state['values']['uploaded_photos'][] = $file;
             $x++;
    } else {
     form_set_error($key, t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
  }
}
```

}

I am trying to save images attached to a form into a cached object with CTools. All of that was working fine, until I tried uploading the same file again, and I got a white screen that said "Error  - The website encountered an error." (ripped from watchdog):

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://ad-10.jpg'; for key 2: UPDATE {file_managed} SET uid=:db_update_placeholder_0, filename=:db_update_placeholder_1, uri=:db_update_placeholder_2, filemime=:db_update_placeholder_3, filesize=:db_update_placeholder_4, status=:db_update_placeholder_5, timestamp=:db_update_placeholder_6
WHERE  (fid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array
(
[:db_update_placeholder_0] =&gt; 0
[:db_update_placeholder_1] =&gt; ad-10.jpg
[:db_update_placeholder_2] =&gt; public://ad-10.jpg
[:db_update_placeholder_3] =&gt; image/jpeg
[:db_update_placeholder_4] =&gt; 4912
[:db_update_placeholder_5] =&gt; 0
[:db_update_placeholder_6] =&gt; 1326221376
[:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 834
)
";s:9:"%function";s:21:"drupal_write_record()";
```

Since I am not setting the $replace argument, shouldn't it default to FILE_EXISTS_RENAME and therefor not throw this error? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this module. It fixes the issue of concurrent file object being written to db. https://drupal.org/project/upload_qc

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment as to why that doesn't work (it looks like it certainly should) but I can offer a simpler solution.

Drupal actually has a form widget built-in to handle file uploads, the [`managed_file`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) type. It handles all of the file uploading/validating for you, you just need to mark the files as permanent in your form's submit handler.

So in your form function:

```
$form['files'] = array('#tree' => TRUE);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_file_fields; $i++) {
  $form['files']["file_$i"] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Select a file',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg')
    )
  );
}
```

And then in your submit handler:

```
$count = count($form_state['values']['files']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['files']["file_$i"]);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Apparently its related to this: http://drupal.org/node/1102308 - will investigate your solution though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because of strange unused temporary files.
You can check if you have unused files using:

```
$result = db_select('file_managed', 'f')
    ->fields('f', array('fid'))
    ->condition('f.uri', db_like('temporary://') . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute()->fetchCol();

foreach ($result as $fid) {
  if ($file = file_load($fid)) {
    if (!file_usage_list($file)) {
      dpm($file->filename);
    }
  }
}
```

If you fail to upload file with the same name that you see, you can remove them(**But** double check and backup first):

```
/**
 * Clean unused temporary files.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_7007() {
  $files = db_select('file_managed', 'f')
    ->fields('f', array('fid'))
    ->condition('f.uri', db_like('temporary://') . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute()->fetchCol();
  foreach ($files as $fid) {
    if ($file = file_load($fid)) {
      $references = file_usage_list($file);
      if (empty($references)) {
        if (!file_delete($file)) {
          watchdog('file system', 'Could not delete temporary file "%path" during garbage collection', array('%path' => $file->uri), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
        }
      }
      else {
        watchdog('file system', 'Did not delete temporary file "%path" during garbage collection, because it is in use by the following modules: %modules.', array('%path' => $file->uri, '%modules' => implode(', ', array_keys($references))), WATCHDOG_INFO);
      }
    }
  }
}
```